# How do I test the behavior inside an ActiveRecord creation block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

How can I test code like this with rspec?

```
Foo.create! do |foo|
  foo.description = "thing"
end
```

I don't want to test of the object was created -- I want to test if the right methods were invoked with the right objects. Equivalent to testing this:

```
Foo.create!(description: "thing")
```

with this:

```
Foo.should_receive(:create!).with(description: "thing")
```

Comment: There are things that no need to test unless description is a custom method, or this is academic interest?

Comment: i need to make sure my client code is assigning the right object to the right attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
it "sets the description" do
  f = double
  Foo.should_receive(:create!).and_yield(f)
  f.should_receive(:description=).with("thing")

  Something.method_to_test
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo.count.should == 1
Foo.first.description.should == 'thing'
```

Comment: But I don't want to test the underlying persistence behavior -- I want to test if the code is setting the right objects to the right places. I added more detail to my question now.

Comment: "I want to test if the right methods were invoked with the right objects."

You can do that by specifying the resulting state, as in @antiqe's example. What benefit do you think you're getting by specifying that `description=` was used vs `write_attribute(:description, "value")`, or any of the other alternatives at your disposal?

Comment: @DavidChelimsky the goal was to not test the persistence qualities of AR creation. I know that each of the methods I am testing work properly, so in order to test the function that uses them I can just test if they are called. I know this isn't so pretty, and the reason the new hotness seems to be to never do controller specs -- only response and/or integration. But anyway back to your point -- YES, it's true, both methods would have the same behavior, so I should test  for their result. So I guess FG build_stubbed and testing resultant values is maybe a good overall solution. Thoughts?

Comment: err, forget my comment about build_stubbed, clearly doesn't apply here since creation is what i'm testing. but the other ponderings still stand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combination approach that merges the best from @antiqe's and @Fitzsimmons' answers. It is significantly more verbose though.

The idea is to mock Foo.create in a way that behaves more like AR::Base.create. Frist, we define a helper class:

```
class Creator
  def initialize(stub)
    @stub = stub
  end

  def create(attributes={}, &blk)
    attributes.each do |attr, value|
      @stub.public_send("#{attr}=", value)
    end

    blk.call @stub if blk

    @stub
  end
end
```

And then we can use it in our specs:

```
it "sets the description" do
  f = stub_model(Foo)
  stub_const("Foo", Creator.new(f))

  Something.method_to_test

  f.description.should == "thing"
end
```

You could also use `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed` instead of `stub_model`. You can't, however, use `mock_model`, `mock` or `double` since you would have the same problem again.

Now your spec will pass for any of the following code snippets:

```
Foo.create(description: "thing")

Foo.create do |foo|
  foo.descrption = "thing"
end

foo = Foo.create
foo.descrption = "thing"
```

Feedback is appreciated!